# Unable to get CSS Attribute selector to work

Tags: css

I'm trying to convert this css to use an attribute "starts-with" selector because I have several anchor elements with id attributes that start off with the same value...

```
a#cta_button_127944_79d30f48-4e68-43c8-949d-a9734a713b32,
a#cta_button_127944_40183a15-c491-4389-b5a8-4cdf099f6003,
a#cta_button_127944_4acbc01a-9116-4540-9bc4-196052464441,
a#cta_button_127944_dc0b71c9-f602-43ac-a318-d18811217e4b
{
    background-color: #336699;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is my wildcard..

```
a[id^="cta_button_127944"] {
    background-color: #336699;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Individual selectors work perfectly. The attribute "starts-with" selector is not getting picked up.

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1pg70pqf/. Can you create a [mcve] in your question?

Comment: working for me ...

Comment: Can you post your HTML? The CSS is correct, so the error may reside on the HTML side.

Comment: The cta is brought in via JS (external). Like I mentioned adding standard styling in our stylesheet works. I'm guessing it's something related to the external handling. I'll dig further.

Comment: Could you also post the generated `HTML`?